# How to style a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a redux form, which looks pretty bad. I want to style it somehow, but my project uses modular css loaders. It looks like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Input = styled.input`
  color: #41addd;

  &:hover {
    color: #6cc0e5;
  }
`;

export default Input ;
```

Then I have to import it into a component which where I want to use that **Input** element.

But redux-form uses a build in component called **`Field`**.

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

      <Field 
        name="firstName"
        component="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
```

And if I would replace `Field` with my customly styled `Input`, the form doesn't work any longer.

How can I deal with it? How can I style the `Field` component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `styled-components` have special functional for that case. Your example will be like so:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const StyledField = styled(Field)`
  color: #41addd;

  &:hover {
    color: #6cc0e5;
  }
`;

<StyledField 
  name="firstName"
  component="input"
  type="text"
  placeholder="First Name"
/>
```